# how to set CPTlegend label text more than one line in core plot?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-plot

[image]

I am added CPTlegend in my pie chart but i am unable to find how to set cptlegend text as more than two lines how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Insert a newline ("`\n`") character in any Core Plot text to break the text into multiple lines.

Comment: But my Core Plot text will come dynamically from my server that time how can i do this one.

Eric Skroch

Comment: You can do it on the server or in your app. It doesn't matter as long as the string passed to Core Plot includes the newline character.